# PulseAudio RTP, how do I unmute the mic?

Tags: pulse-audio

We have set up an RTP connection between two Ubuntu machines, and are attempting to send audio from a headset mic from one computer to the other.  Computer A is the sender, B the receiver.  When the session is established, I am able to see data being received on B but I cannot hear anything.  When the user on A opens up her sound settings, the mic is automatically un-muted and B can hear her voice.  The auto un-muting is not consistent, and it seems that the settings pane can't be open when pulse is started.  How can we set the settings in the default.pa file to do what opening the sound settings pane does to the mic?  So far, we have tried:
- setting the default source
- disabling auto-mute via the alsamixer

And I found this command on the troubleshooting wiki "pactl set-source-mute 1 toggle" but we are trying to do our entire setup via config files because we will not have a GUI available.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in our default.conf file.  Prior to loading module-udev-detect, we needed to include this module first:

load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0  (with the numbers being unique to our machines and found via pacmd arecord that lists hardware input devices)